# Where to upload hdfs files?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

hadoop and hdfs seem to be running for me correctly as when I navigate to

`http://127.0.01:50070/dfshealth.jsp` I receive this output :

[image]

But when I try to run the code

```
public class firstmapreducedriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JobClient client = new JobClient();
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(firstmapreducedriver.class);

        // TODO: specify output types
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("dfs"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("Out"));

        // TODO: specify a mapper
        conf.setMapperClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.class);

        // TODO: specify a reducer
        conf.setReducerClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer.class);

        client.setConf(conf);
        try {
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I receive this error :

```
13/03/04 19:53:33 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
13/03/04 19:53:51 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/03/04 19:53:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:9100/tmp/hadoop-newuser/mapred/staging/newuser/.staging/job_201303041945_0001
13/03/04 19:53:51 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:newuser cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9100/user/newuser/dfs
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9100/user/newuser/dfs
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at firstmapreducedriver.main(firstmapreducedriver.java:44)
```

Where can I configure the location of the hdfs files or where do I need to create the dir "dfs" so that it is found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you specified the directories:

```
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("dfs"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("Out"));
```

Any relative path (one that does not start with `/`) will have a root of `/user/$USER`.  So, you have to make sure that your input path of `/user/newuser/dfs` exists and has data inside of it.  You can execute the following to make the directory and put in files:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/newuser/dfs
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal localFile.txt /user/newuser/dfs/
```